# Place Activity Code correctly in Android Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android

I am trying to include the generation of a random number in an android project with Navigation Drawer Menu. For the latter I’ve been following a youtube tutorial (Android Development Tutorials #12 - Generating a Random Number) which worked perfectly, but only in a basic android studio project. Being a java-newbie, I get stuck when trying to include the same Java Code into MainActivity.java that already contains the code for the Navigation Drawer Menu. I assume that the spot where I insert the respective sample code for number generation (Lines 114 to 126 in snippet) must be wrong somehow, and I’ve been trying different approaches within the file. But I always get the error: unreachable statement (in Line 114). Thx for any help in advance!

```js
package...

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        if (id == R.id.nav_first_layer) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame
                            , new FirstFragment())
                    .commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_second_layer) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame
                            , new SecondFragment())
                    .commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_third_layer) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame
                            , new ThirdFragment())
                    .commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;

        final TextView textOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rndsampletext);

        Button pushMe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rndsamplebutton);

        final String [] txtOptions = {"One", "Two", "Three"};

        pushMe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int rando = (int) (Math.random() * 3);
                textOne.setText(txtOptions[rando]);
            };
        });

    }


}
```

Comment: You might be able to take some inspiration from [here](https://github.com/Zhuinden/simple-stack/blob/master/simple-stack-example-mvp/src/main/java/com/zhuinden/simplestackdemoexamplemvp/application/MainView.java)

Answer (score 0):

you are returning true at begining:

```
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;  // here
```

it should be after u generate the random number:

I suggest u add the code to your `onCreate()` method of the `activity`

Like:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    //move this here
    final TextView textOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rndsampletext);

    Button pushMe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rndsamplebutton);

    final String [] txtOptions = {"One", "Two", "Three"};

    pushMe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int rando = (int) (Math.random() * 3);
            textOne.setText(txtOptions[rando]);
        };
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

Comment: @trav6 Welcome to Stack overflow...if the answer helped mark it as correct by clicking the tick sign next to the Answer..thankx

Comment: Thx you very much for your help, indeed, rafsanahmad007!! I did what you suggested (i.e. moving return true), and the initial problem was gone. However, when launching the app in the emulator, it starts perfectly, but when clicking on the 'first layer' in the drawer menu, the app stops... Don't know yet what could be the problem. I tried to remove the code from lines 114-126 and it all worked like a charm. Any idea? You also suggestet the alternative with adding the code into onCreate() instead. How did you mean that?

Comment: i have edited the answer with the meaning...hope it helps

Comment: Great, thank you very much. Unfortunately, I still have app breakdowns when trying to run it (I don't have them when removing the respective codelines...). With the alternative approach you suggested the app stopps earlier than with the first method. I'm trying to debug it and maybe make a clean new build of it, then might return.